# python ray not completing all remote calls

Tags: python, ray

so i have a simple a script

```
import ray
import requests as r

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def f(i):
    print(i)
    r.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/" + str(i))
    return i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for k in range(1000):
        f.remote(k)
```

when i run this script only 250 remote calls happens and the program terminates instead of executing all the 1000 remote calls.

i really have no clue even after viewing the ray browser dashboard

when i set local_mode=True the program complete all the 1000 calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.remote(k)` *starts* executing the remote calls, but doesn't wait for the calls to finish. Therefore the program finishes and shuts down before the calls finish.

You should use `ray.get` to make sure the calls finish.

```
refs = []
for k in range(1000):
    refs.append(f.remote(k)
ray.get(refs)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63539577/script-breaks-out-of-function-after-sending-a-few-packets/63543408#63543408) for more details.